# How to write typescript code such that output should be like

Tags: javascript, html, typescript, web-applications, ecmascript-5

```
class Test {
    otherFunction() {}
    method() {
        this.otherFunction();
    }
}
```

Above typescript will generate ES5 js like this

```
var Test = /** @class */ (function () {
    function Test() {
    }
    Test.prototype.otherFunction = function () { };
    Test.prototype.method = function () {
        this.otherFunction();
    };
    return Test;
}());
```

How to get output like below function after compiling typescript?

```js
var Test = (function() {
    function Test() {}

    function otherFunction() {}

    Test.prototype.method = function () {
        otherFunction();
    }

    return Test;

})();
```

Comment: It looks like something that would be output if you target an earlier ES version in your tsconfig.json

Comment: Do you mean what is TS equivalent of this?

Comment: ```
class Test {
 otherFunction() {}
 method() {
  this.otherFunction();
 }
}
```
above code will generate below js 
```
var Test = /** @class */ (function () {
    function Test() {
    }
    Test.prototype.otherFunction = function () { };
    Test.prototype.method = function () {
        this.otherFunction();
    };
    return Test;
}());
```
which is not expected. i need like this
```
var Test = (function() {
  function Test() {}

  function otherFunction() {}

  Test.prototype.method = function () {
    otherFunction();
  }

  return Test;

})();
```

Answer (score 0):

Compile this one

```
(function () {
  function Test() {}

  function otherFunction() {}

  Test.prototype.method = function () {
    this.otherFunction();
  };

  return Test;
})();
```

It will generate

```
(function () {
    function Test() { }
    function otherFunction() { }
    Test.prototype.method = function () {
        this.otherFunction();
    };
    return Test;
})();
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. 
But, First code is not in typescript it javascript. In question, if you check first snippet is typescript, second is generated. but I need typescript code which generate code like third one.